# consume dynamic id in document.getelementbyID

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-4.0

I am using asp.net 4.0

I have a checklistbox and a checkbox. I have to select all checkbox on of checklisbox on checking the checkbox.I am writing  the following code.

```
function Select(CheckBox, ChecklistBoxID) {
    var TargetBaseControl = document.getElementById('<%= chkAction.ClientID%>');
    var Inputs = TargetBaseControl.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var n = 0; n < Inputs.length; ++n)
        Inputs[n].checked = CheckBox.checked;
}
```

My query is, in the above function, I am passing second parameter for checklistbox, How to pass this id in below line of code.

```
var TargetBaseControl = document.getElementById('<%= chkAction.ClientID%>');
```

EDIT
I have two more checklistbox, So i don;t want to hardcode the controlID. I was thinking of passing the ID as parameter. thus the code will become reusable...

```
 <asp:CheckBox ID="chkact" onclick="javascript:Select(this, 'chkAction');"  ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text="Select All" />
```

Comment: Please check my appended Edit.

Comment: How is `Select` being called?

Comment: Please find it at the bottom of query

Comment: It's a checklist box and i am selecting and doing vice versa on changing the checkbox by using the select function.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3500/discussion-between-pankaj-and-daniel-a-white)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below was the fix.

The checklboxlist need to initialize a property ClientIDMode = "Static". Finally i could ascertain the ID using below code.

```
var TargetBaseControl = document.getElementById(ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean to do this:

```
var TargetBaseControl = document.getElementById(ChecklistBoxID);
```

Where `ChecklistBoxID` is the id of the control that contains all the input elements.

That will work without problems since you are passing the ID as a string; like you are doing here, for example:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkact" onclick="javascript:Select(this, 'chkAction');"  ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text="Select All" />
```

**UPDATE:**  It appears that the `Select` function is defined in the MasterPage; therefore the code behind in the respective content page will need to spit out the javascript as so:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
     chkact.Attributes.Add("onclick","Select(this,'"+listbox.ClientID+"');");
}
```

Comment: NO. It's not possible. I have a content page(I meant page is using the master page), so <%=  syntax is necessary.

Comment: So your `Select` function is declared in the Master Page? If that's so, you need to generate the javascript code you attach to your checkBox from code behind. I will update my answer.

Comment: @Pankaj check my update. If that doesn't do it, then I don't understand your question.